# My vuejs applications step function stops just before submit

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a step form with 3 steps and it stops at third step before submission.
On debugging it is found methos not allowed exception.
my code is as below

```
if(this.step == 39){
                console.log(this.readinessAssessment); 
                console.log(this.jobSeekerId);  
                    this.showLoader = false;
                    axios.post('/save-competencies', {readinessAssessment: this.readinessAssessment, jobSeekerId: this.jobSeekerId})
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response.data.success){
                            this.competenciesPart = false;
                            this.applicationAccepted = true;
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.step = 100;
                            }, 1000);

                            this.hideProgressBar = false;
                            this.hideProcess = false;

                        }
                        this.showLoader = false;

                    }).catch(error => {
                        this.showLoader = false;
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
```

My route is

```
Route::post('/save-competencies', [FrontendController::class, 'saveCompetencies'])->name('saveCompetencies');
```

Comment: Kindly mention the error properly and what you expect?

Comment: I am getting stuck when clicking submit after last radio button in the step form It is a qustion which people answer and submit. When inspected in console it is showing 500.

Comment: On following this link saying get method is not supported for this route. Methos allowed is post

Comment: My data is an array of 18 elements

Comment: Array(18)
0: {question: 'some question', answer: 'Occasional', weightedScore: '0.5', competency: 'Adaptability'}
1: {question: 'Isome question', answer: 'Occasional', weightedScore: '0.5', competency: 'Adaptability'}
2: {question: 'some question', answer: 'No', weightedScore: '0.25', competency: 'Collaboration'} ....

Comment: Is there  size limit for post ? Or  is it an error from vuejs? I have no clue on this error

Comment: There is no issue of post size request.

Comment: kindly run `php artisan optimize:clear` in laravel project

Comment: After it run composer dump:autoload

Comment: Thank you. That is a perfect fix. My code worked by running these 2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is which you mentioned in comment is: `Error: On following this link saying get method is not supported for this route. Methos allowed is post`

The solution of this issue is.

Run these two commands in your **Laravel** project

> php artisan optimize:clear

> composer dump:autoload

This will fix the route method type issue.

Comment: Thank you. This cleared the issue. Now all working perfect

Comment: @Mrs.Mani thanks, Its my pleasure